# How to add "<>" symbols to a string?

Tags: python

Basically the issue is that I need my variable `Tagged_input` to print at the very last line as such `'<'tag'>' + first_half + '<'tag'>'`. I have been unsuccessful in trying to insert the `<>` `</>` into the string.

I thought perhaps this can be fixed on the line where i actually create the variable but no clue where to begin.

```py
#Create Midpoint variable

midpoint = int( string_length / 2 )

#Slice the string into 2 equal halves
first_half, second_half = user_input[:len(user_input)//2],
user_input[len(user_input)//2:]

#Calculate new string using concatenation of tag and first_half
tagged_input = tag + first_half + tag

#Calculate length of tagged_input
tag_length = len( tagged_input )

#calculate the whitespace needed
spaces_needed = int(80 - tag_length / 2, )
#Create a variable for whitespace which can be used in calculations
x=" "

#Print the whitespace then the string
print( spaces_needed * x + tagged_input )
```

Comment: Can you refactor that into a [mcve] that we can copy.paste and execute? There are a lot of unknown variable names in your example.  what are `string_length`, `user_input`? Maybe include input and desired output.

Comment: What have you actually tried, and what was the wrong output or error from your attempt?

Comment: What's the problem if you just write + between the strings in your attempt?

Comment: `"<" + tag + ">"` ? OR using string formatting `"<{}>{}</{}>".format(tag, first_half, tag)` or `f-string` - `f"<{tag}>{first_half}</{tag}>"`

Comment: It's worth noting that while you *can* do what you're asking about with fairly simple string formatting operations, if you need to do it on any sort of larger scale, it might make sense to use an XML or HTML library instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to add Python variables into a string there are multiple ways to go about it:

- [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
- [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- `+`

```
hey = "Hello"
earth = "World"

string = f"<{hey}> <{earth}>"
print(string)  # <Hello> <World>

string = "<{}> <{}>".format(hey, earth)
print(string)  # <Hello> <World>

string = "<" + hey + "> <" + earth + ">"
print(string)  # <Hello> <World>
```

Perhaps using `f-string` might make your life easier and your code more easily maintanable. :)

Comment: Why didn't you add the `<>` symbols in any of the examples?

Comment: Generalized answer. I assume OP can apply the concepts above with the use of `<>`. Would you say it would be better practice to be less generalized on answering SO questions (serious inquiry)?

Comment: IMO, when someone asks such a basic question, it would probably be best to be specific — and assume/hope they can generalize it themselves from the example.

Comment: Duly noted for the future. I'll be more specific -- thank you for tip!

Comment: Thanks for the help this solved my issue. pretty much used the + to fix it. Heres the new code.  tagged_input = '<' + tag + '>' + first_half + '</' + tag + '>'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to achieve the result you want.

```
"<{0}> {1} <{0}>".format(tag, first_half)
```